# Сайты для быстрого обмена фрагментами кода в команде

Tags: c#, javascript, java, team

Подскажите сайты для быстрого обмена кодом (c#, java, javascript, ...), чтобы можна было, например, кинуть ссылку на сайт и другой человек сразу же увидил сохраненный мною фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну хотя бы [paste bin](http://pastebin.com) и [github gists](https://gist.github.com)

Answer (score 4):

- [gist](gist.github.com)
- [dpaste](dpaste.de)
- [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/)
- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)
- [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)