# как из shell-а опубликовать в интернете текстовую информацию?

Tags: shell, faq

у меня возникла проблема с машиной, и при её обсуждении в интернете меня попросили выложить содержимое файла (например, `/etc/os-release`) и вывод программы (например, `ping -c 3 google.com`), а затем прислать ссылки спрашивающему.

как мне это сделать попроще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

опубликовать текст можно на сайте типа pastebin.com или его клоне.

а чтобы было «попроще», можно установить пакет [`pastebinit`](https://launchpad.net/pastebinit), присутствующий в репозиториях, вероятно, всех популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux* (а если нет, то по приведённой ссылке можно скачать этот скрипт на *python-е*).

пример (ссылки — рабочие на момент публикации). можно передать аргументом имя файла, содержащего текст, а можно передать скрипту поток, формируемый командой:

```
$ pastebinit /etc/os-release 
http://paste.debian.net/287649/
$ ping -c 3 google.com | pastebinit -b http://pastie.org
http://pastie.org/10320757
```

или сформировать «пасту» из нескольких источников:

```
$ { dmesg | grep eth; echo; grep notice /var/log/apache2/error.log; } | pastebinit -b http://paste2.org
http://paste2.org/OjtwyHxt
```

---

список известных скрипту сайтов можно посмотреть так: `pastebinit -l`.

по умолчанию, если не указан сайт (при помощи опции `-b url`), адресом назначения будет дистро-специфичный сайт (в приведённом примере — `paste.debian.net`).

---

по поводу иных похожих сайтов — посмотрите ответы к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/304731/178576).

Comment: На OS X тоже есть: `brew install pastebinit`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, теоретически, ничто не препятствует этому скрипту работать даже под *ms/windows*.