# Firewalld: запрет всех подключений, кроме явно разрешённых

Tags: linux, firewall

Каким образом заблокировать все порты, кроме двух-трёх?

Порядок открытия портов я нашел, а порядок четкого запрета подключения нет.

**UPD**.
Необходимо закрыть всё, кроме 22 25 и 5432 портов. Но при этом не через iptables, а средствами сервиса *firewalld* (*RHEL 7.2*).

**UPD**.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [70735:6495007]
:INPUT ACCEPT [41964:2503520]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [90187:5911322]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [90187:5911322]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_dmz - [0:0]
:POST_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:POST_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:POST_dmz_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o ens33 -g POST_dmz
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_dmz
-A POST_dmz -j POST_dmz_log
-A POST_dmz -j POST_dmz_deny
-A POST_dmz -j POST_dmz_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens33 -g PRE_dmz
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_dmz
-A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_log
-A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_deny
-A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4232940:2432546121]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4226525:2431921025]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2761324:5621790553]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2761333:5621792532]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens33 -g PRE_dmz
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_dmz
-A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_log
-A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_deny
-A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [4203811:2428532287]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2761324:5621790553]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4232940:2432546121]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2761324:5621790553]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 27 13:14:27 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2761324:5621790553]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:FWDI_dmz - [0:0]
:FWDI_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:FWDI_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:FWDI_dmz_log - [0:0]
:FWDO_dmz - [0:0]
:FWDO_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:FWDO_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:FWDO_dmz_log - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:IN_dmz - [0:0]
:IN_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:IN_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:IN_dmz_log - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i ens33 -g FWDI_dmz
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_dmz
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o ens33 -g FWDO_dmz
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_dmz
-A FWDI_dmz -j FWDI_dmz_log
-A FWDI_dmz -j FWDI_dmz_deny
-A FWDI_dmz -j FWDI_dmz_allow
-A FWDO_dmz -j FWDO_dmz_log
-A FWDO_dmz -j FWDO_dmz_deny
-A FWDO_dmz -j FWDO_dmz_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -i ens33 -g IN_dmz
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_dmz
-A IN_dmz -j IN_dmz_log
-A IN_dmz -j IN_dmz_deny
-A IN_dmz -j IN_dmz_allow
-A IN_dmz_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_dmz_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: В apf это 1 строчка =/

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Каких протоколов порты, например. Как вы их разрешаете. Закрывать на входе/выходе/форварде. А то ведь `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` гарантированно закроет все, входящее на машину. Ну или вообще установка дефолтной политики `iptables -P INPUT DROP`, только в таком виде ответный трафик на машину то же закроется.

Comment: *четкого запрета нет* — после беглого ознакомления с [документацией](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD/ru) делаю вывод, что по умолчанию подразумевается «запрещено всё, что явно не разрешено». мне сейчас негде проверить эту гипотезу, но если вы [выложите куда-нибудь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438972/178576) вывод `sudo iptables-save` (подозреваю, что он слишком велик для вставки в вопрос), то можно будет сказать точнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Порядок открытия портов я нашел, а порядок четкого запрета подключения нет.

дополнительных «запретов» не требуется.
запрещено всё, что не разрешено явно. приложенное содержимое таблиц *netfilter-а* это подтверждает.

все пакеты извне обязательно проходят через цепочку *input* таблицы *filter*, через эти правила (я оставил только существенные строки):

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
...
-A INPUT_ZONES -i ens33 -g IN_dmz
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_dmz
-A IN_dmz -j IN_dmz_log
-A IN_dmz -j IN_dmz_deny
-A IN_dmz -j IN_dmz_allow
-A IN_dmz_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_dmz_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

да, по умолчанию «политика» у цепочки — *accept*, но заканчивается обработка цепочки директивой `--jump REJECT` — отклонить пакет. он будет отклонён, если до этого не попал под действие какой-нибудь разрешающей директивы.

---

проверить закрытость какого-нибудь произвольного порта *tcp* несложно. например, так:

1. на проверяемой машине запускаем процесс, слушающий порт (к примеру — 3333) на всех сетевых интерфейсах:

   ```
   $ nc -l 3333
   ```
2. подключаемся извне к этому порту тестируемой машины:

   ```
   $ telnet тестируемая.машина 3333
   ```

   если подключиться удалось, получим что-то вроде:

   ```
   Trying тестируемая.машина...
   Connected to тестируемая машина.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   ```

   если не удалось, то получим что-то вроде:

   ```
   Trying тестируемая.машина...
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
   ```