# При нажатии клавиши не генерируется keypress event

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура

Ни в одной программе (включая консоль), я не могу нажать W без шифта - программа попросту игнорирует нажатие. С "Ц" та же история.

Xev показывает только `keyrelease event` для данной клавиши, а `keypress event` отсутствует:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
root 0x2c0, subw 0x3000002, time 1663198, (33,24), root:(98,76),
state 0x10, keycode 25 (keysym 0x77, w), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

В терминале (без гнома) все работает корректно.
Т.е. вроде как код идет, ОС его понимает. Но дальше оперировать с ним отказывается. Где может быть проблема?

Comment: а перед `keyrelease event` разве не было `keypress event` по поводу той же самой клавиши? [выложите куда-нибудь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438972/178576), на всякий случай, вывод `$ xkbcomp $DISPLAY -` (минус в конце — это второй параметр).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/f9ARDLL5
Поправил выдачу Xev. KeyPress не выдает

Comment: уточните, правильно ли я вас понял: вы нажимаете клавишу, но в выводе xev не появляется `keypress event`, а когда отпускаете, появляется `keyrelease event`? такое поведение наблюдается только у данной клавиши, или встречается и у других клавиш? другие клавиатуры ведут себя так же?

Comment: не определено ли в настройках вашего wm (window manager) клавиатурное сокращение (keyboard shortcut) для этой клавиши?

Comment: Да, keypress event не появляется (вместо него появляется keymapnotify и focusin\focusout.
В терминале клавиатура ведет себя корректно - значит проблема в иксах, а не клавиатуре. Но я не разбираюсь в том, как иксы обрабатыват клавиатуру и какие инструменты отвечают за настройку всего этого дела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отсутствие `keypress event` как раз и приводит к тому, что «клавиша не нажимается». точнее, программа (при проверке это программа `xev`), которая создала окно, в данный момент владеющее фокусом, не получает оповещения о том, что такая-то клавиша нажата.

если это «обычная» клавиша (не какая-нибудь «мультимедийная», или модификатор типа <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>), причём заведомо работоспособная, то отсутствие события говорит, скорее всего, о том, что данное событие перехвачено на «более высоком» уровне.

например, в *wm* (*window manager*, например, *metacity*), где за данной клавишей может быть закреплено какое-нибудь действие (так сказать, «создан shortcut»).

---

следовательно, в первую очередь стоит **перепроверить «клавиатурные» настройки** вашего *wm*. при использовании *de* (*desktop environment*, например, *gnome*) такие настройки обычно интегрированы во что-то типа «панели управления».

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @alexander barakin
В менеджере горячих клавиш когда-то нечаянно поставил w на яркость экрана. Отключил. Заработало.