# Подключение статической библиотеки в качестве модуля Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, cocos2d

Здравствуйте. Стоит задача использовать библиотеку **protobuf-3.3.0** в андроид приложении.

1. С помощью **Сygwin**  получил **libprotobuf-lite.a**
2. Cоздал **Android.mk**

   > LOCAL_PATH := $(call my_dir)
   >
   > ```
   > include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
   >
   > $(warning $(LOCAL_PATH)) 
   >
   > LOCAL_MODULE := libprotobuf-lite 
   >
   > LOCAL_SRC_FILE := libprotobuf-lite.a 
   >
   > include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
   > ```
3. Изменил основной **..\proj.android\jni\Android.mk**
   3.1. Добавил:

   - $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external/protobuf) Если я правильно понимаю я должен указать путь к Android.mk, описанный выше.
   - ../../Classes/GSToGC.pb.cc \ Файл скомпилированный protoc
   - LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external/protobuf/include Путь к .h файлам protobuf (protobuf/include/google/protobuf/..)
   - LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static \ 
     libprotobuf-lite \ Добавил имя модуля, который должен подключить libprotobuf-lite.a

> ```
>  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
>
>     include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
>
>     $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d) 
>     $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external) 
>     $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external/protobuf) 
>     $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos) 
>     $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos/audio/include) 
>
>     LOCAL_MODULE := MyGame_shared 
>
>     LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libMyGame 
>
>     LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/ComputerScene.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/ComputersListScene.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/ExchangeScene.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/MainScene.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/UtilFormatMoneyStr.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/UtilInitLabelMoney.cpp \ 
>                    ../../Classes/Player.cpp \ 
> ../../Classes/GSToGC.pb.cc \ 
>
>     LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes 
>     LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external/protobuf/include  
>     # _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN 
>     # _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END 
>
>
>
>     LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static \ 
>     libprotobuf-lite \ 
>     # _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN 
>     # _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END 
>
>     include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) 
>
>     $(call import-module,.) 
>
>     # _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN 
>     # _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
> ```

4. PS E:\Projects\MiningSimulator\Client\proj.android> cocos compile -p android --ndk-mode=release --ap andoid 19
   Выдает ошибки error: undefined reference . Как я понимаю не находит .сpp файлы, которые лежат в libprotobuf-lite.a. Что я делаю не так?
   Полный лог: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SvD4CgVE)

П.С. Что-то я испортил с разметкой.

Comment: Переложите логи в нормальное место, к примеру, на пастебин

Comment: *к примеру, на пастебин* — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438972/178576

Comment: Сделано. Теперь буду знать. Есть какие-то соображения по поводу проблемы?